# Compare location of x y values between two dataframes

Tags: r, lapply, purrr

I have two data frames (A & B), each with columns of  x and y coordinates. For a given row in A, I want to know if there is a row (or multiple rows) **anywhere** in B that have values of B(X) and B(Y) that are each within a range of +/- 0.2 of the values in A(X) and A(Y). I also need to know the position of this row in B.

Example data:

```
AX<-c(1:5)
AY<-c(1.2,2.2,3.5,4.3,5.5)
A<-data.frame(AX, AY)
BX<- c(0.8,0.9,3.8,6,2.1)
BY<- c(1.1,1.4,4,7,2.4)
B<-data.frame(BX,BY)
```

The solution is like this:

For row 1 of A- rows 1 and 2 of B are within the range

For row 2 of A- row 5 of B is within the range

For row 3 of A- no row of B is within the range,

and so on.

Essentially I am trying to find xy points in B that are near xy points in A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using base R :

```
lapply(asplit(A, 1), function(x) which(rowSums(abs(sweep(B, 2, x)) <= 0.2) == 2))


#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[2]]
#[1] 5

#[[3]]
#integer(0)

#[[4]]
#integer(0)

#[[5]]
#integer(0)
```

Comment: What about if the data frames have multiple other columns as well as the x and y?

Comment: and you want to compare only for `x` and `y` ignoring other columns? You could subset columns by name `A[c('x' 'y')]` or by position `A[1:2]` for both `A` and `B`.